# PHP foreach comparing 2 multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this function below that works fine without the `& $rQtyOld==$data1[$k1]['rQty']` part, but when I add it as an additional criteria it returns false and does not execute the code `$data1[$k1]['rQty']=$addition[$i]['rQty'];` .

I validated that `$rQtyOld===$data1[1]['rQty']` in some instances. `$rQtyOld` is defined previously this way:`$rQtyOld=$_POST['editionFormerQty'];`

The $data1 array looks something like this:

```
[{"name":"56.030","type":"F","rQty":"888"},{"name":"20.242","type":"T","rQty":"22"},{"name":"20.242","type":"T","rQty":"10"}]
```

And the code

```
function adjustKeyToArray($data1,$addition,$rQty,$rQtyOld){
    $iLength=sizeof($addition);     
    foreach($data1 as $k1=>$v1){            
        for($i=0;$i<$iLength;$i++){             
            if($addition[$i]['name']==$data1[$k1]['name'] & 
               $addition[$i]['type']==$data1[$k1]['type'] & 
               $rQtyOld==$data1[$k1]['rQty'])
            {
                $data1[$k1]['rQty']=$addition[$i]['rQty'];                  
                return $data1;          
            }
        }       
    }
    return $data1;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work?
Thanks,

Comment: Your IF statement is using bitwise operator &, this should be && for a logical operator.

Comment: Did you `json_decode($data1)` before passing it to this function or are you passing it in as a JSON String?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I `json_decode($data1)` before passing it on.

Comment: Did you var_dump it after json_decode? Maybe it hasn't decoded properly. Try json_decode($data1, true);